# Can't append textArea from another class with contructor object

Tags: java, methods, append, jtextarea

I'm trying to append text. My `println` works fine inside the `appedText` method, but I can't append what I send from the other class. I can do it if I make the method String and return the result.

I would appreciate any please. Also I have tried all the things with the constructors "this.textArea" etc.

```
public class BetParser   {

    public    JMenuBar  menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    public    JMenu menu, submenu;
    public    JMenuItem menuItem;
    public    JTextField textField;
    public    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
    public    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BetBrain Parser");
    public    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    public    JLabel gridlabel = new JLabel("");
    public    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    public    JButton button;
    public    URL url;

    public BetParser(){}

    public BetParser(JTextArea textArea){
      this.textArea=textArea;
    }

    public  void createAndShowGUI() {
      //some code here for the gui

      htmlparser parseitem = new htmlparser();   

      try {
          parseitem.JsoupParser(sitelink);
    }
}
```

I made the `appendText` method and doesn't works when I call the method from htmlparser class

```
public void appendText(String msg){
    textArea.append(msg+"\n");
    System.out.println("skata me fraoules");
}
```

And here is the `htmlparser` class I use above.

```
public class htmlparser {

     public htmlparser(){  
     }

     public void  JsoupParser(String url) throws IOException{
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
       Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
       System.out.println(doc.title());

       BetParser parserItem = new BetParser();

       parserItem.appendText(doc.title());
   }   
}
```

Comment: Please, start following [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). And on your `appendText` you're affecting `textArea` instead of the argument `textArea1`.

Comment: You want to append the text in the method appendText, where you have both references, the message you append and the text area. If that is the case, then it seems like the second argument is not a JTextArea class. What error do you exactly get. Please forward the error with the stack trace.

Comment: as i have say i have checked everything with this argument, i just forgot it there textArea, textArea1 its the same argument , i got getTExt which returns jtext so when i call the append as you can see its the same textarea. And to finish i get no error just nothing on my frame. But in my console the print ln works fine. So the hmtl parser calls the method correct, but the textArea append doesnt work.

Comment: And if you read above i said that i can make it work if i make the method in htmlparse String and return the value i want , but the thing here is tha i want to understand why this isnt working. ty

Comment: Aribeiro , i can name the variables and classes how ever i want thats the concept , so i can remember them, if you read the java naming convetions you will read that what i said. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are creating an instance of `BetParser` here:

```
public  void createAndShowGUI() {
//some code here for the gui
```

If so, don't create it again in the `JsoupParser(String url)` just pass the first one as a parameter. So your new `JsoupParser` would be like that:

```
public void  JsoupParser(String url,  BetParser parserItem) throws IOException{

   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
   Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
   System.out.println(doc.title());

   parserItem.appendText(doc.title(), parserItem.getText());

}
```

Comment: Is `JsoupParser` only place that creating `BetParser`?

Comment: I cant unterstand your question my friend , if you could say it little different Ty

Comment: `BetParser` has two constructor. You are calling the empty one in `JsoupParser`. Are you calling `public BetParser(JTextArea textArea)` from anywhere? I am asking this, because I suspect `textArea.append(msg+"\n");` this textArea is a different instance, not the created one at first place.

Comment: i call the default constructor in main

Comment: Then define `JsoupParser()` as I mention above, and call it like that `parseitem.JsoupParser(sitelink, this);` in `createAndShowGUI()`.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested your code but I noticed that you're not referencing the variable you pass in appendText():

Here it's `textArea1`

```
public void appendText(String msg, JTextArea textArea1){
```

and here it's `textArea`

```
textArea.append(msg+"\n");
```

Is that part of the problem?

Comment: I ll remove it , because its the same variable